# How to change parameters in retry request after error in RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I send a login request to server with retrofit 2.0, and server return to the client session token, wich I must use in other requests, but this token has limited life-time, and when it is expire server returns HTTP error 401.

I try make re-logon, after getting this error, with help a next code:

```
    holder.getApi(GuideProfileApi.class)
      .getProfile(String.valueOf(holder.getServerId()), holder.getServerToken())
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .retryWhen(new Function<Observable<Throwable>, ObservableSource<?>>() {
         @Override
         public ObservableSource<?> apply(Observable<Throwable> throwableObservable) throws Exception {
           return throwableObservable.flatMap(new Function<Throwable, ObservableSource<?>>() {
             @Override
             public ObservableSource<?> apply(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
               if (throwable instanceof HttpException &&  ((HttpException)throwable).code() == 401) {
                 RegistryLoginResult loginResult = holder.login().blockingSingle();
                 return holder.getApi(GuideProfileApi.class)
                    .getProfile(String.valueOf(loginResult.getUserId()), loginResult.getSessionToken());
               }
               return Observable.error(throwable);
            }
        });
     }
  })
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(new Consumer<ProfileResult>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(ProfileResult profileResult) throws Exception {
      Log.d("Result", profileResult.toString());
    }
  }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
      @Override
      public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
        Log.e("Result", throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
      }
});
```

And retry request is sent, but parameters of request are same as in incorrect request (before re-login). How I can change parameters of the request before sending it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong operator. `retryWhen` will retry your **original observable** if it encounters an error. What you need is `onErrorResumeNext`. Something like

```
 holder.getApi(GuideProfileApi.class)
      .getProfile(String.valueOf(holder.getServerId()), holder.getServerToken())
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .onErrorResumeNext(new Function<Throwable, ObservableSource<?>>() {
        @Override
         public ObservableSource<?> apply(Throwable throwable) {
               if (throwable instanceof HttpException &&  ((HttpException)throwable).code() == 401) {
                 RegistryLoginResult loginResult = holder.login().blockingSingle();
                 return holder.getApi(GuideProfileApi.class)
                    .getProfile(String.valueOf(loginResult.getUserId()), loginResult.getSessionToken());
               }
               return Observable.error(throwable);
        }
    }) 
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(new Consumer<ProfileResult>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(ProfileResult profileResult) throws Exception {
      Log.d("Result", profileResult.toString());
    }
  }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
      @Override
      public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
        Log.e("Result", throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
      }
});
```

Comment: How to exclude `return holder.getApi(GuideProfileApi.class)
                    .getProfile(String.valueOf(loginResult.getUserId()), loginResult.getSessionToken());` and change params of the **original observable**?

Comment: I believe Observables in rxjava are immutable. Once you've created an observable you can't go back and change it.

Comment: Thank you for consultation.

Comment: But what if the second observable encounters an error and you want to retry again? It seems like the defer solution offered by paul is much cleaner.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `retryWhen`, but the problem is that your retryWhen retry the same observable object that you create in lazy moment. 
Your solution here is use the operator `defer` to get the host(), since defer it´s not creating the observable when you define it but when it´s consumed by the subscribed.

```
Observable.defer(()-> holder.getApi(GuideProfileApi.class)
          .getProfile(String.valueOf(holder.getServerId()),holder.getServerToken()))
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .retryWhen(new Function<Observable<Throwable>, ObservableSource<?>>() {
     @Override
     public ObservableSource<?> apply(Observable<Throwable> throwableObservable) throws Exception {
       return throwableObservable.flatMap(new Function<Throwable, ObservableSource<?>>() {
         @Override
         public ObservableSource<?> apply(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
           if (throwable instanceof HttpException &&  ((HttpException)throwable).code() == 401) {
             RegistryLoginResult loginResult = holder.login().blockingSingle();
             return holder.getApi(GuideProfileApi.class)
                .getProfile(String.valueOf(loginResult.getUserId()), loginResult.getSessionToken());
           }
           return Observable.error(throwable);
        }
    });
 }
  })
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(new Consumer<ProfileResult>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(ProfileResult profileResult) throws Exception {
      Log.d("Result", profileResult.toString());
    }
      }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
          @Override
          public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
            Log.e("Result", throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
          }
    });
```

You can see some examples of retry here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/errors/ObservableExceptions.java